# Consequences for interpretation of: "Coefficients: (X not defined because of singularities)"

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, singular-matrix

In the following example data, coefficients (country-year dummies) are excluded because of singularities.

My question is not necessarily how to solve this (although if there is way to recategorise these dummies, to avoid the perfect multicollinearity, that would be great), but more to understand what this means for my results.

I am worried that the singularities bias the effect of my IV and that I can no longer trust the coefficients.

## Question

Does the exclusion of these coefficients change the validity or the interpretation of my result?

## Background

The `ivreg` package gives the option to include instrumental variables to the regression. Everything before the `|` is the original model. After the `|` is the model with instruments.

## Data

The data looks as follows:

```
panelID= c(1:50)
year= c(2005, 2010)
country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
urban = c("A", "B", "C")
indust = c("D", "E", "F")
sizes = c(1,2,3,4,5)
n <- 2
library(AER)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(   country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                    sales= round(rnorm(10,10,10),2),
                    industry = rep(sample(indust, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    urbanisation = rep(sample(urban, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                    size = rep(sample(sizes, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(base_rate = as.integer(runif(1, 12.5, 37.5))) %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(taxrate = base_rate + as.integer(runif(1,-2.5,+2.5)))
DT <- DT %>%
group_by(country, year) %>%
mutate(vote = sample(c(0,1),1), 
votewon = ifelse(vote==1, sample(c(0,1),1),0))
```

## Scenario 1

```
summary(ivreg(sales ~ taxrate + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + country:as.factor(year) | as.factor(votewon) + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + country:as.factor(year), data=DT))


Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-11.755  -2.666   0.502   2.774  10.742 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                    -4.599      7.318   -0.63   0.5317   
taxrate                         0.485      0.239    2.03   0.0458 * 
as.factor(industry)E            0.194      1.643    0.12   0.9062   
as.factor(industry)F            1.488      1.707    0.87   0.3862   
as.factor(size)2                3.086      1.779    1.74   0.0870 . 
as.factor(size)3                1.999      2.152    0.93   0.3560   
as.factor(size)4                4.289      1.774    2.42   0.0181 * 
as.factor(size)5                2.250      2.125    1.06   0.2932   
as.factor(urbanisation)B       -0.772      1.746   -0.44   0.6599   
as.factor(urbanisation)C        0.796      1.612    0.49   0.6230   
countryA:as.factor(year)2005   -7.386      3.972   -1.86   0.0671 . 
countryB:as.factor(year)2005    5.551      3.548    1.56   0.1220   
countryC:as.factor(year)2005    3.913      4.034    0.97   0.3352   
countryD:as.factor(year)2005   -2.807      3.706   -0.76   0.4512   
countryE:as.factor(year)2005    4.080      4.102    0.99   0.3233   
countryF:as.factor(year)2005    1.219      4.660    0.26   0.7944   
countryG:as.factor(year)2005   -7.845      3.629   -2.16   0.0339 * 
countryH:as.factor(year)2005    1.876      5.051    0.37   0.7115   
countryI:as.factor(year)2005    7.804      3.235    2.41   0.0184 * 
countryJ:as.factor(year)2005  -10.362      3.041   -3.41   0.0011 **
countryA:as.factor(year)2010    0.833      3.903    0.21   0.8316   
countryB:as.factor(year)2010    3.823      3.548    1.08   0.2848   
countryC:as.factor(year)2010    5.019      4.034    1.24   0.2174   
countryD:as.factor(year)2010   -0.287      3.706   -0.08   0.9384   
countryE:as.factor(year)2010    1.590      3.764    0.42   0.6741   
countryF:as.factor(year)2010    7.602      4.839    1.57   0.1206   
countryG:as.factor(year)2010   -5.994      3.497   -1.71   0.0908 . 
countryH:as.factor(year)2010    7.043      5.051    1.39   0.1675   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.4 on 72 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.379,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.146 
Wald test: 1.63 on 27 and 72 DF,  p-value: 0.0526
```

## Scenario 2

```
summary(ivreg(sales ~ taxrate + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + as.factor(vote) + country:as.factor(year) | as.factor(votewon) + as.factor(industry) + as.factor(size) + as.factor(urbanisation) + as.factor(vote) + country:as.factor(year), data=DT))


Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-11.755  -2.666   0.502   2.774  10.742 

Coefficients:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                    -4.599      7.318   -0.63   0.5317   
taxrate                         0.485      0.239    2.03   0.0458 * 
as.factor(industry)E            0.194      1.643    0.12   0.9062   
as.factor(industry)F            1.488      1.707    0.87   0.3862   
as.factor(size)2                3.086      1.779    1.74   0.0870 . 
as.factor(size)3                1.999      2.152    0.93   0.3560   
as.factor(size)4                4.289      1.774    2.42   0.0181 * 
as.factor(size)5                2.250      2.125    1.06   0.2932   
as.factor(urbanisation)B       -0.772      1.746   -0.44   0.6599   
as.factor(urbanisation)C        0.796      1.612    0.49   0.6230   
as.factor(vote)1                7.043      5.051    1.39   0.1675   
countryA:as.factor(year)2005   -7.386      3.972   -1.86   0.0671 . 
countryB:as.factor(year)2005   -1.492      4.199   -0.36   0.7234   
countryC:as.factor(year)2005   -3.130      3.608   -0.87   0.3885   
countryD:as.factor(year)2005   -9.851      6.122   -1.61   0.1119   
countryE:as.factor(year)2005    4.080      4.102    0.99   0.3233   
countryF:as.factor(year)2005    1.219      4.660    0.26   0.7944   
countryG:as.factor(year)2005  -14.889      6.995   -2.13   0.0367 * 
countryH:as.factor(year)2005    1.876      5.051    0.37   0.7115   
countryI:as.factor(year)2005    7.804      3.235    2.41   0.0184 * 
countryJ:as.factor(year)2005  -10.362      3.041   -3.41   0.0011 **
countryA:as.factor(year)2010   -6.211      6.463   -0.96   0.3398   
countryB:as.factor(year)2010    3.823      3.548    1.08   0.2848   
countryC:as.factor(year)2010   -2.024      3.608   -0.56   0.5765   
countryD:as.factor(year)2010   -0.287      3.706   -0.08   0.9384   
countryE:as.factor(year)2010   -5.454      3.802   -1.43   0.1557   
countryF:as.factor(year)2010    7.602      4.839    1.57   0.1206   
countryG:as.factor(year)2010   -5.994      3.497   -1.71   0.0908 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.4 on 72 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.379,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.146 
Wald test: 1.63 on 27 and 72 DF,  p-value: 0.0526
```

Comment: Could you explain how a problem with a statistical procedure could possibly affect the validity of the data?  In what sense do you mean "validity" here?  And concerning the second part of your question, could you tell us what the interpretation is that you think might change?  What is the original interpretation you have in mind and what is the changed one?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. I should have said validity of the results/coefficients (I will change that).

Comment: @whuber For the second part, I am worried that the estimate of the IV can no longer be trusted. In other words, that the removal of country-year dummies, creates a bias for the IV and hence the `taxrate`.